# Reactjs : setState doesn't assign value to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help, and you are the only ones to give me that :D
I'm learning reactjs, trying to develop a simple fight game.

I try to update one state (on the line below) to define whose turn to give a hit it is:

*this.setState({whoseRound: rand}, console.log('test:' + this.state.whoseRound))*

and it won't update my state. My state value still is 0. I can't understand why, if someone could save me !

thanks to everyone.

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      characters: [], //contains Array of characters objects
      readyToFight: false, // character selected or not
      firstPlayerCharacter: null, //contains key of character on select
      secndPlayerCharacter: null, //contains key of character on select
      whoseRound: 0 // defines whose character attacks
    }
  }

  //Run the fight
  setFight = () => {
    let firstFighter = this.state.characters[this.state.firstPlayerCharacter]
    let secndFighter = this.state.characters[this.state.secndPlayerCharacter]

    this.initiateFight(firstFighter, secndFighter);
  }

  //initiate fight rounds
  initiateFight = (firstFighter, secndFighter) => {

    // set who attacks first randomly => returns 1 or 2
    var rand = randomDice(1, 2)

    // !!!!! HERE: My console.log always display 0
    this.setState({whoseRound: rand}, console.log('test:' + this.state.whoseRound))

    while(firstFighter.stats.health > 0 || secndFighter.stats.healthh > 0){
      // depending on whoseRound is, we set an attacker and a defenser
      1 === this.state.whoseRound ? this.runRound(firstFighter, secndFighter) : this.runRound(secndFighter, firstFighter)
    }
  }

  // Lance les actions définies pour un round
  runRound = (attacker, defender) => {
    let hit = false
    let cc = false
    let damages

    hit = randomDice(0, 100) <= this.getHitChances(attacker, defender)
    cc = randomDice(0, 100) <= this.getCriticalChances(attacker, defender)
    damages = this.getDamages(attacker, defender, cc)

    if(hit)
    {
      //console.log(attacker.name + ' attaque ' + defender.name + ' et lui occtroie ' + damages + ' points de dégats')
      //console.log('les points de vie de ' + defender.name + ' passent de ' + defender.stats.health + ' à ' + (defender.stats.health - damages))
      defender.stats.health -= damages
    }

    //Now, it's the other character's turn
    1 === this.state.whoseRound ? this.setState({whoseRound: 2}) : this.setState({whoseRound: 1})

  }
  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. The question should be re-opened or at least marked as a duplicate of an *actual* duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in `setState()` is a callback. In other words, it takes a function. So you have to wrap the code you want executed in a function.

Like this:

```
// !!!!! HERE: My console.log always display 0
this.setState({whoseRound: rand}, function() {console.log('test:' + this.state.whoseRound)})
```

Or with an arrow function, if you prefer:

```
// !!!!! HERE: My console.log always display 0
this.setState({whoseRound: rand}, () => {console.log('test:' + this.state.whoseRound)})
```

Comment: Thanks ! How didn't i see that. But now, my question is: As sateState is asynchrone, must I put the while below in the callback function then ? Or is there a cleaner way to do that ?

Comment: For a better understanding, visit: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b

Comment: And the same problem will popup in the end of my runRound function :/

Comment: Thx, i'll read it as a bible !

Comment: @Janus, your function seems alright. What problem is there?

Comment: The problem is that as the satestate function asynchron, when the script enters the loop below, the whoseRound state hasnt been updated yet and stills at 0.

Comment: Then, i suppose i'll have the same problem at the end of my runRound function.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't have a while-loop

Comment: But if I dont, how could I loop my rounds ? :D